# PHP Crawler - Why is readdir while loop quitting when it reaches empty folder?

Tags: php, recursion, while-loop, web-crawler, readdir

I have the following function as part of a larger program that crawls the contents of a provided path, and indexes any .htm or .html pages that it finds in the parent folder or any subfolders.  My crawler function (below) is recursive, and seems to work just fine, UNTIL it reaches enters a subfolder that contains no items.

This seems to be a common problem that is often fixed by structuring the while loop as follows:

```
while ( false !== ($file = readdir($folder)) )
```

but this isn't working.  The last line that gets output is 'The current crawler path is ...', and then the output just stops.  I'm guessing the problem is the empty folder and the readdir function, but I don't know how to fix it.  Can someone offer a suggestion?

Thanks

```
function crawlFolders($path)
{
    $prevPath = $path;  // variable to keep track of the previous file path
    chdir($path);
    $folder = opendir($path);

    echo "The current crawler path is ".$path."<br>";

    while ( false !== ($file = readdir($folder)) ) // read current directory item, then advance pointer
    {   
        if ( is_file($file) )
        {   echo "File found!  The crawler is inspecting to see if it can be indexed<br>";
            if ( canIndex($path."/".$file) )
                indexPage($path."/".$file);
        }

        else if ( is_dir($file) ) 
        {
            //it's a folder, we must crawl
            if ( ($file != ".") && ($file != "..") )    //it's a folder, we must crawl
            {
                echo "$file is a folder<br><br>";
                crawlFolders($path."/".$file);
                chdir($prevPath); // change the working dir back to that of the calling fn

            }
        }   
    }
    closedir($folder);

}
```

After looking at this some more, I can't see why readdir is causing the problem.  I think the problem may be that my crawlFolders function is not unwinding itself, and is instead just ending when it reaches the deepest, empty folder.  Am I missing something with the way the recursion should work?  I was under the impression that the recursive function calls would exit once the while loop returned false, thus dropping me to the previous crawlFolders function that made the recursive call (i.e. unwinding itself).

Do I need to return a value each time crawlFolders exits, so that the calling function knows where to resume itself?

It definitely seems like the recursion is the problem.  I placed a file in the empty folder and my indexer worked, but the functions still didn't unwind as I wanted.  I know this isn't happening because there are still two files in the starting path that weren't evaluated.

Comment: Your code looks correct, can you make sure that you are seeing PHP errors if they occur (error_reporting/display_errors)?

Comment: Not familiar with the error reporting but I turned it on and didn't see anything show up.  I added some more to my original post... I'm beginning to think that the recursion isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the recursion but very likely the current working directory.

You change the current directory using `chdir()` and then with `$file` you give a relative filename to `is_file()` and `is_dir()`. After the execution returns from the recursion the current directory is still the subdirectory so `is_file($file)` and `is_dir($file)` won't find the files.

You have to save the current directory before you go into the recursion or - better - avoid `chdir()` altogether and work with full paths: `is_file($path . '/' . $file)`

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I don't see where $path is being reassigned as it enters the recursive function.  I assign the $path value elsewhere in the program and don't re-assign it in when crawling, I just append the $file variable.

So... Entering the function the path = $path.  When crawlFolders is called I pass: `crawlFolders($path."/".$file)`.  Shouldn't $path be the same as it originally was when we return from the recursive call, seeing that I appended $file to the path string, rather than reassigning with `$path = $path."/".$file;` ?

Comment: I am talking about the `chdir($path)` that changes the *current working directory* which is global (not restored on return) and which is used as the reference when you pass relative filenames to functions like in `is_file($file)`.

Comment: I was under the impression that since I'm passing `$path` by value and not by reference, that a new copy of `$path` is created with each recursive function call.  As such, I thought this copy would be discarded when the each layer of recursion unwinds.

Is the issue here that, while `$path` is passed by value, it's treated as a global because `crawlFolders()` is still only seen as one function, regardless of how many instances exist due to the recursive calls?

Hopefully I'm making sense... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, everything you said about the variable `$path` is absolutely true. But I am not talking about `$path` but I'm talking about the *current working directory* of the PHP process. Please read the manual for `chdir()` and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory. Or just remove the `chdir()` from your code.

Comment: Many thanks...I finally got it.  Code above updated and working now.  FYI the text I'm using says it's best to use `chdir()` when exploring folders, as sometimes a filename might get confused and mistaken for a folder.  Perhaps this isn't the best way to handle this, but I'm trying to solve the problem given the functions that have been taught up to this point in my course.  Now I just need to tweak things so it crawls alphabetically and with folders first, then files.  Thanks again for steering me in the right direction.